# Can I combine two 'findAll' search blocks in beautifulsoup, into one?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Can I combine these two blocks into one:

Edit: Any other method than combining loops like Yacoby did in the answer.

```
for tag in soup.findAll(['script', 'form']):
    tag.extract()

for tag in soup.findAll(id="footer"):
    tag.extract()
```

Also can I multiple blocks into one:

```
for tag in soup.findAll(id="footer"):
    tag.extract()

for tag in soup.findAll(id="content"):
    tag.extract()

for tag in soup.findAll(id="links"):
    tag.extract()
```

or may be there is some lambda expression where I can check whether in array, or any other simpler method.

Also how do I find tags with attribute class, as class is reserved keyword:

EDIT: this part is solved by the soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'noprint'}):

```
for tag in soup.findAll(class="noprint"):
    tag.extract()
```

Comment: you'll get better results if you only post one question per question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass functions to `.findall()` like this:

```
soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name in ['script', 'form'] or tag['id'] == "footer")
```

But you might be better off by first building a list of tags and then iterating over it:

```
tags = soup.findAll(['script', 'form'])
tags.extend(soup.findAll(id="footer"))

for tag in tags:
    tag.extract()
```

If you want to filter for several `id`s, you can use:

```
for tag in soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.has_key('id') and
                                    tag['id'] in ['footer', 'content', 'links']):
    tag.extract()
```

A more specific approach would be to assign a lambda to the `id` parameter:

```
for tag in soup.findAll(id=lambda value: value in ['footer', 'content', 'links']):
    tag.extract()
```

Comment: SyntaxError? Strange... you should get a TypeError.

Comment: for tag in soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag['id'] in ['footer', 'content', 'links']) does not work. KeyError: 'id' I am using Py2.6, it that helps.

Comment: This works though: for tag in soup.findAll(id=lambda(value): value and value in ['catlinks', 'siteSub', 'contentSub'])

Comment: i pasted the wrong version, sorry. this correction guards against tags that don't have the id attribute.

Comment: your version works too, of course, but i wanted to show a more general approach

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if BeautifulSoup can do it more elegantly, but you could merge the two loops like so:

```
for tag in soup.findAll(['script', 'form']) + soup.findAll(id="footer"):
    tag.extract()
```

You can find classes like so ([Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching%20by%20CSS%20class)):

```
for tag in soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'noprint'}):
    tag.extract()
```

Comment: Its working good, but doesn't look clean combining long loops ...+...+...+...+...+...+...+...Is there any other better method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the second part of your question is *right there* in the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29):

> **Searching by CSS class**
>
> The attrs argument would be a pretty obscure feature were it not for one thing: CSS. It's very useful to search for a tag that has a certain CSS class, but the name of the CSS attribute, class, is also a Python reserved word.
>
> You could search by CSS class with soup.find("tagName", { "class" : "cssClass" }), but that's a lot of code for such a common operation. Instead, you can pass a string for attrs instead of a dictionary. The string will be used to restrict the CSS class.
>
> ```
> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
> soup = BeautifulSoup("""Bob's <b>Bold</b> Barbeque Sauce now available in 
>                    <b class="hickory">Hickory</b> and <b class="lime">Lime</a>""")
>
> soup.find("b", { "class" : "lime" })
> # <b class="lime">Lime</b>
>
> soup.find("b", "hickory")
> # <b class="hickory">Hickory</b>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
links = soup.find_all('a',class_='external') ,we can pass class_ to filter based on class values

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen('http://www.espncricinfo.com/') as f:
    raw_data= f.read()
    soup= BeautifulSoup(raw_data,'lxml')
    # print(soup)
    links = soup.find_all('a',class_='external')
    for link in links:
        print(link)
```