# Beautiful Soup: Trying to select tags on conflicting multiple criteria

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

In **BeautifulSoup** is it possible to select all instances of a tag `li` whose Class has a specific value `(= 'hidden')` OR the Class attribute is not present at all?

How would I write the `findAll` statement to achieve this?  I searched a lot but could not find a similar question.

The page I am trying to scrape has three types of 'li' tags:

```
li  (no class attribute)  
li  (class = more  )  
li  (class = hidden )
```

I want to pick all `li` tags that are of the 1st and 3rd type only.
Is it possible in Beautiful soup to structure a `findAll('li'....)` that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to solve it via [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
no_class_at_all = soup.find_all("li", class_=False)
hidden_class = soup.find_all("li", class_="hidden")
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe - that gets me much closer to a solution!  However, If I do Classes_I_need = soup.find_all("li", class_=(False or "hidden"))  ; it does not throw an error but returns only the hidden classes.       Alternatively, in the code that you provide above, is it possible to merge the two results? i.e. Classes_I_need = no_class_at_all + hidden_class?  Thanks!

Comment: @imfundo you cannot approach it with `Classes_I_need = soup.find_all("li", class_=(False or "hidden"))` since `False or "hidden"` would always return you "hidden". And `soup.find_all("li", class_=[False, "hidden"])` would not work either. In other words, just "concatenate" up the two lists `no_class_at_all + hidden_class`?

Comment: Thanks @alecxe - that was very helpful! I tried this approach and seems to be working though there are other issues in my code that might be confounding the outcome. Once I've made it work, I'll confirm.  Thanks again! Best.

Comment: Hi @alecxe, I found this post very relevant and on the spot as well...    [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825187/can-i-combine-two-findall-search-blocks-in-beautifulsoup-into-one). Thanks again!